# chef knife stucked on completion for a command

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I keep getting a stuck completion or frozen status when I run this command from my workstation to my node.

```
knife ssh -x centos 'name:*' -i /home/centos/downloads/chef.pem 'sudo yum install httpd'
```

Can't I send Linux command through knife?

Comment: Does the `centos` user have password-less access to `sudo yum`?

Comment: it does not but I am using a pem key

Comment: PEM key will allow you to SSH and run commands, it doesn't overcome password prompt for `sudo`. Try running a non-privileged command like `date` or `hostname`. If it works, and not `sudo yum` then configure password-less `sudo` for the user.

Comment: I will try that thanks!